# pyenv 'system' version inconsistent with 'real' python version

Tags: python, pyenv

In my ubuntu 16.04 system I have the following **pyenv** versions

```
$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /home/myuser/.pyenv/version)
3.6.0
3.6.0/envs/general
general
```

I intend that the version named `system` should coincide with the ***real*** `system` one, but when I check which python version will be executed, I get:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.0
$ which python       # expecting /usr/bin/python
/home/myuser/.pyenv/shims/python
```

instead of the expected `/usr/bin/python` symlink which points to `python2.7`

```
$ ll /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 apr 18 10:11 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7*
```

Why is that? Is there something that I understand wrong?

How do I reset the pyenv `system` to make it coherent with the *real* `system`? I want to be sure of using the real system python when executing normal commands in my home dir.

Comment: What python do you get if you $python3

Comment: `$ python3 --version` gets me `Python 3.6.0` while the real system one is the symlink `/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5`